# ActiveMQ within Wildfly on a Docker container gives: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected

Tags: docker, activemq-classic, wildfly

I have Wildfly running in a Docker container.
Within Wildfly the messaging-activemq subsystem is active.
The subsystem and extension defaults are taken from the standalone-full.xml file.

After starting wildfly, following output is displayed

```
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64)
AMQ121005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector.
Switching to "eeb79399d447".
If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
```

The eeb79399d447 is the docker container id.
It's also impossible to connect to jms from my java client. While connecting it gives the following error.

```
AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: eeb79399d447
```

When I start wildfly on my local workstation (outside docker) the problem does not occur and I can connect to jms and send my messages.

Comment: You need to describe the environment in which your "client" is executing. The command that you use to run the WildFly docker instance would also be handy. In general docker host names are only visible to other docker containers.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options. Option 1 & 2 may be what you asked for, but in the end didn't work for me.  Option 3 however, I think will better address your intent.

**Option 1)** You can do this by adding some scripting to your docker image ( and not touching your `standalone-full.xml`.  The basic idea ( credit goes to git-hub user kwart ) is to make a docker entry point that can determine the IPv4 address of the docker container before calling `standalone.sh`.

see : https://github.com/kwart/dockerfiles/tree/master/wildfly-ext and check out the usage of `WILDFLY_BIND_ADDR`.  I forked it.

Notes:

- GetIp.java will print out the IPv4 address ( and is copied into the container )
- dockerentry-point.sh calls GetIp.java as needed

```
    WILDFLY_BIND_ADDR=${WILDFLY_BIND_ADDR:-0.0.0.0}
    if [ "${WILDFLY_BIND_ADDR}" = "auto" ]; then   
      WILDFLY_BIND_ADDR=`java -cp /opt/jboss GetIp`
    fi
```

**Option 2)** Alternatively, using some script-fu, you may be able to do everything you need in a Dockerfile:

```
#CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "standalone-full.xml", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "DOCKER_IPADDR=$(hostname --ip-address) && echo IP Address was $DOCKER_IPADDR && /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml -b=$DOCKER_IPADDR -bmanagement=$DOCKER_IPADDR"]
```

**Your mileage may very.**

I was working with the `helloworld-jms` quickstart from the WildFly docs, and had to jump through some extra hoops to get the JMS queue created.  Even at that point, the sample java code wasn't able to connect with either option 1 or option 2.

**Option 3)** ( *This worked for me btw* ) Start your container with binding to 0.0.0.0, expose your 8080 port for your JMS client running on the host, and add an entry in your hosts' /etc/hosts file:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
# CP foo.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent
RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh -a quickstartUser quickstartPwd1! --silent
RUN echo "quickstartUser=guest" >> /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/application-roles.properties
# use standalone-full.xml to enable the JMS feature
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "standalone-full.xml", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Build & run ( expose 8080 if your client is on your host machine )

```
docker build -t mywildfly .
docker run -it --rm --name jboss -p127.0.0.1:8080:8080 -p127.0.0.1:9990:9990 my_wildfly
```

Then on the host machine ( I'm running OSX; my jboss container's id was 46d04508b92b ) add an entry in your `/etc/hosts` for the docker-host-name that points to 127.0.0.1:

```
127.0.0.1 46d04508b92b  # <-- replace with your container's id
```

Once the wildfly container is running, you create/configure the testQueue via scripts or in the management console.  My config came from `https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart.git` under the `helloworld-jms` folder:

```
docker cp configure-jms.cli jboss:/tmp/
docker exec jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --file=/tmp/configure-jms.cli
```

and SUCCESS from `mvn clean compile exec:java` the host machine (from w/in the `helloworld-jms` folder):

```
Mar 28, 2018 9:03:15 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
INFO: Found destination "jms/queue/test" in JNDI
Mar 28, 2018 9:03:16 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
INFO: Sending 1 messages with content: Hello, World!
Mar 28, 2018 9:03:16 PM org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient main
INFO: Received message with content Hello, World!
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the standalone-full.xml to cope with jms behind NAT and when you run the docker container pass though the ip and port that your jms client can use to connect, which is the ip of the machine running docker in Dockers' default config

Comment: How exactly edit the standalone-full.xml? What to add? Can you be more precise please?

Comment: please provide more detail in the event you have a solution